# How to convert c# object to native NSObject

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I am having the object data in which current datasource item is stored in forms. I need to map the item to native item.

```
NSObject obj = (NSObject) data;
```

It shows the error as cannot convert `object` to `NSObject` and Cast is not applicable .

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

use [NSObject.FromObject()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/foundation.nsobject.fromobject#Foundation_NSObject_FromObject_System_Object_)

```
var nso = NSObject.FromObject(csobject);
```

Comment: it returns null for nso

Comment: This works only for particular types and while @DeviM hasn't disclosed what type is 'data' it is safe to assume that it isn't among those types according to its name. BTW, I am not sure if you or OP have downvoted my answer (or both as there are 2 downvotes), but it is correct so I'll keep it.

Answer (score -2):

Obviously you can't do it, there is no 1 line that will resolve the problem, you have to do hard work and create the new instance of the class that derives from NSObject (or whatever native class) and set the properties there.